# The item failed due to an error occurring when sending or receiving data to the external content processing enrichment web service

Tags: sharepoint-search, content-enrichment

I have Created a content enrichment service (CEWS) for SharePoint enterprise search in SharePoint 2013.

I have a condition in the CEWS, so if the managed metadata property is not null then it will be search item will be sent to the CEWS.

Currently I its showing error in the search crawl logs.
**The item failed due to an error occurring when sending or receiving data to the external content processing enrichment web service. ( Failed to process the results returned by the content processing enrichment service.; ; SearchID = )**

Looking more into the ULS logs and find the actual error as below.

### ULS Log details

### 0x18D4  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Gatherer Service        fus3    Medium  Transaction failed in plugin IPOC Url sts4s://siteurl=teams/CSTest/siteid=/weburl=/webid={}/listid={}/folderurl=/itemid=25079 Error 0x8004fd31  [gthrtrx.cxx:950]  search\native\gather\gthrsvc\gthrtrx.cxx

Anyone faced this issue. Please revert if you have any clue.

While troubleshooting the issue I have tried below steps. but none of these helped to solve the issue.

1. Full Crawl/Index reset/Service restart/Server restart
2. Created new search service app and corresponding CEWS

Comment: Can you clarify this statement: "I have a condition in the CEWS, so if the managed metadata property is not null then it will be search item will be sent to the CEWS" I do not understand.

Comment: Can you post the code?